# Empty fields are validated on one environment but not on other environment

Tags: jsf-2, bean-validation

I have the same JSF war deployed in two environments, both environments are apparently identical (Weblogic 10.3.3). There is no entry in the `web.xml` for `javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS`. 
In one of the environments, the validators are getting invoked on empty fields and in the other they are not. 
The JSF war and the application code is EXACTLY the same.

The JSF Specification version is 2.0 and Implementation Version is 1.0.0.0_2-0-2. I know I can add the parameter `javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS` in web.xml to ensure identical behavior in all environments, but I want to know why they have a different default behavior? Is it possible that it could be something related to presence of JSR 303 validation in one environment and not in another? How do I check this?

Comment: What validators exactly are you talking about? The JSF `required="true"`? Or the JSR303 `@NotNull`? Or the Hibernate Validator specific `@NotEmpty` or `@NotBlank`?

Comment: I am talking about validators defined using f:validator in the JSF page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSR 303 validation is auto enabled if the implementation jar is on the classpath.

Comment: Thanks Xie, I will check that and respond.

Comment: What is the implementation jar I should be looking for? I could only find commons-validator.jar in the classpath when I Searched for a jar file having "valid" in its name.

Comment: Is there a way to check programmatically if JSR-303 validation is present in the environment?

Comment: It's hibernate-validator-4.2.0.jar in my case. I don't know how to check whether JSR-303 is enabled for JSF 2.0, but you can get all validation providers by `ServiceLoader.load(ValidationProvider.class)`. You may set context init-parameter `javax.faces.validator.DISABLE_DEFAULT_BEAN_VALIDATOR` to `true` to disable the bean validator.